# p:remoteCommand updating a component works incorrectly

Tags: primefaces, remotecommand

We have a **RemoteCommand** (showOnlineUsers) that calls a backing bean method to show all the online users. But it does not **(*sometimes*)** update the **component** (OnlineUsersFormId:onlineUserId).

```
<p:remoteCommand name="showOnlineUsers" 
                 action="#{bean.showOnlineUsers()}" 
                 update="OnlineUsersFormId:onlineUserId" />
```

This remote command supposed to update the following h:panelGroup

```
<h:form id="OnlineUsersFormId">
    <h:panelGroup id="onlineUserId">
        <ui:repeat var="user" value="#{bean.usersList}">
            #{user.getUserName()}
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

This code works fine but after some time it behaves abnormally and it generates incomplete partial-response messages in **Chrome-Network-Debugger.**

**Correct generated msg:**

```
<partial-response id="j_id1">
   <changes>
     <update id="OnlineUsersFormId:onlineUserId">
       <span id="OnlineUsersFormId:onlineUserId"></span>
     </update>
     <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">-938130356222711200:-4155932992558832648
     </update>
  </changes>
</partial-response>
```

**Incorrect generated msg:**

```
<partial-response id="j_id1">
   <changes>
     <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">-938130356222711200:-4155932992558832648
     </update>
   </changes>
</partial-response>
```

As you clearly can see that **OnlineUsersFormId:onlineUserId** is missing from incorrect generated partial-response in Google Chrome's network debugger.
That is why (I guess), it does not update the panelGroup component on the page.

**Note:** Once it does not update the component, it repeats the same message in debugger, unless we refresh the page.

Comment: Hi, always create an [mcve]... e.g. what does `action="#{bean.showOnlineUsers()}"` do (in mcve! flavour)? And you know `"#{bean.getUsersList()}"` can be written as `"#{bean.usersList}"`?

Comment: Hi Kukeltje, backing bean method provides a list of Users.

Comment: READ about an [mcve]...